# Laravel 5.7 Route [role.user] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I can't figure out why it isnt working, i have a page to manage user role, and the only way that i can access my user role page is through browser. I mean.. if i do a view route like that, it just dont work. (Only for role.user). role.index and role.create are working just fine.

```
{{route('role.user')}}
```

I've read about resources and such.. I just dont get it. How can i solve that error. And is there a better way to do it?

my app.blade.php for extends:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('role.index')}}">Permissão</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('role.create')}}">Criar Permissão</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('role.user')}}">Editar Usuário</a>

    </nav>
@yield("content")
```

and i defined it in my web.php route as resource:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', ['as'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'role:administrador','uses'=> function(){
    return view ('admin.index');
}
]);
Route::resource ('role', 'RoleController');
Route::resource ('user', 'UserController');
```

My UserController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $allRoles = Role::all();
        return view('admin.role.user', compact(['users','allRoles']));
    }
```

error:

```
"Route [role.user] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\adminLayout\app.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\adminLayout\app.blade.php)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the route is user.index; it is not role.user. If you want to create role.user you have to define it first. The resource controller does not automatically define role.user.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code, please visit [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers). you used custom Route instead "CRUD" routes and it is wrong!

Comment: I've checked it before, i just couldn't figure out what i was doing wrong, thanks for the help.

Comment: When use Route::resource it creates just these actions: index,create,store,show,edit,update,destroy. you have to create other custom routes yourself.